# Calculate totals in product matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Imagine I run a grocery shop and wish to know the popularity of my products.
How do I get totals for each product from the table `fruit` where `1` represents the presence of a product in an order, and `null` -- its absence.

```
order | apples | oranges | kiwis
================================
    1 |      1 |       1 | 
    2 |        |       1 | 
    3 |        |       1 |     1
    4 |      1 |         |     1
    5 |      1 |       1 |     1
```

The result I'm after is:

```
apples:  3
oranges: 4
kiwis:   3
```

What I've tried so far:

```
select count(*) from fruit where apples  = '1'
union
select count(*) from fruit where oranges = '1'
union
select count(*) from fruit where kiwis   = '1'
```

This works, but I can't know which row corresponds to which product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra column to identify the product:

```
select 'apples' as productName, count(*) from fruit where apples  = '1'
union
select 'oranges', count(*) from fruit where oranges = '1'
union
select 'kiwis', count(*) from fruit where kiwis   = '1'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to turn your columns into rows, them count the rows for each fruit:

```
SELECT  upvt.FruitName,
        [Count] = COUNT(*)
FROM    fruit AS f
        UNPIVOT
        (   HasFruit
            FOR FruitName IN ([Apples], [Oranges], [Kiwis])
        ) AS upvt
GROUP BY upvt.FruitName;
```

If you remove the aggregate function you can see what the unpivot is doing, the following query:

```
SELECT  upvt.*
FROM    (VALUES
            (1,1,1,NULL),
            (2,NULL,1,NULL),
            (3,NULL,1,1),
            (4,1,NULL,1),
            (5,1,1,1)
        ) AS f ([Order], apples, oranges, Kiwis)
        UNPIVOT
        (   HasFruit
            FOR FruitName IN ([Apples], [Oranges], [Kiwis])
        ) AS upvt;
```

Will yield:

```
Order   HasFruit    FruitName
------------------------------
1       1           apples
1       1           oranges
2       1           oranges
3       1           oranges
3       1           Kiwis
4       1           apples
4       1           Kiwis
5       1           apples
5       1           oranges
5       1           Kiwis
```

Then it is just a simple group by and count to get the results you want. If you can also have `0` for a column to indicate it won't exist, then change your count to `COUNT(NULLIF(upvt.HasFruit, 0))`

Comment: Thanks, Gareth, for the advanced solution. Maybe too advanced for my limited SQL expertise, but `UNPIVOT` will surely come in handy in later scenarios.